Samba Share with multiple owners on client system
I have a large data folder on one of my servers that for reasons too long to go into, I would like to move to a dedicated NAS (Openmediavault) then share back to the existing server.
Within this are files that are owned by www-data (nextcloud data folder), will (me), media (a plex data folder) and cctv (a recording store for cameras) amongst some other content.
Is there an easy way to maintain an ownership structure like this within a shared storage, or would I be better off breaking each of the folders down into separate shares and mounting them individually?
Ideally I would like to simply maintain the existing owners of the folders and files. I have cloned the drive image for testing but despite selecting the correct-sounding "Inherit Permissions" setting
The permissions on new files and directories are normally governed by create mask and directory mask but the inherit permissions parameter overrides this. This can be particularly useful on systems with many users to allow a single share to be used flexibly by each user.

But on mounting the drive on the server (cloned for testing) via an fstab entry
//10.10.10.65/willzpool /willzpool cifs credentials=/root/smbcredentials 0 0

everything inside the share is owned by root. Even as root, I'm unable to chown anything inside the share.
Am I missing something or is my goal impossible?

I didn't see any mention of Ubuntu and version in the question. "Inherit Permissions" simply let the sub-folders inherit the permissions of the parent folder. So if you copy your folder /server_data/ into the parent folder /NAS_Storage/ so that you have /NAS_Storage/server_data/, then the sub-folder server_data/ will inherit the permission of the parent folder /NAS_Storage/, which I assume is owned by root.

AFAIK there is no way to preserve ownership and permissions in samba. Samba is good for sharing files between Windows and Linux. You will need something like Network File System (NFS) that is native to Linux assuming your NAS supports it. You may have to create these users www-data, will, media and cctv in your NAS. However that may not work as www-data etc. can't be used to login to the server.

Apologies. The server is running 24.04. The owner of the files on the NAS is irrelevant, it's the client that matters. Plex is accessing the /willlzpool/media directory as a member of the media group, nextcloud needs its /willzpool/nextcloud directory owned by www-data with permissions of 0770. I've never really used NFS much because of its lack of authentication but OMV supports it so I might have a play and see what it's like. I did manager to get everything working by sharing each folder as a separate samba share and setting the uid/gid in /etc/fstab but I'm going to try NFS too

Sounds like you found a solution. Separate samba share with their own uid and gid in fstab sounds like a good solution. Please write your own answer and then add to it if NFS works.

Ok so I was able to solve this in two ways.
With Samba, even if the samba user has access to the share, they still need file system permissions to the enclosed files.
So in order to accomplish my goal, I would have either needed to use multiple samba users each with different file system access rights (including one who would have had access to www-data owned folders which didn't seem like a great idea) OR I could chown the entire data folder with one user, share each folder separately, and deal with file ownership on the client.
That's what I did and it worked.
I chowned everything in the data dir as a user with samba access and in the client fstab I did this
//10.10.10.65/cctv /willzpool/cctv cifs credentials=/root/smbcredentials,uid=1010,gid=1010 0 0
//10.10.10.65/media /willzpool/media cifs credentials=/root/smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1003 0 0
//10.10.10.65/nextcloud /willzpool/nextcloud cifs credentials=/root/smbcredentials,uid=33,gid=33,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770 0 0
//10.10.10.65/virtshare /willzpool/virtshare cifs credentials=/root/smbcredentials,uid=1004,gid=1003 0 0
//10.10.10.65/will /willzpool/will cifs credentials=/root/smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0

This gave each folder the correct ownership and permissions on the client and it all worked, but I was uncomfortable about the fact that the ownerships on the NAS server had to be changed. I wanted to retain the ability to detach the drive from OMV and reattach it to the Ubuntu server if required and use it directly so I wanted to keep the ownerships and permissions on the actual folder the same.
NFS took a little more work, I had to create users and groups on the server that matched the client.
The export was pretty simple
export/willzpool 10.10.10.62(fsid=xxxx,rw,no_subtree_check,secure,no_root_squash) 10.10.10.68(fsid=xxxx,rw,no_subtree_check,secure,no_root_squash)

no_root_squash probably isn't recommended, but I wanted to retain the ability to control file ownership on the client by chown-ing files and folders if necessary.
On the client, I setup a new fstab entry
10.10.10.65:/export/willzpool /willzpool nfs defaults  0 0

Unfortunately this failed to mount the share for some reason. I suspect it was trying to mount it before the network was up. I tried adding _netdev to the fstab entry but it made no difference. I suppose I could have figured it out, but I just set a cronjob to run at boot
mount -a

which solved the problem.
I had to do a little fiddling with the share for my camera recording which I shared as NFS from the new OMV server but that turned out to be a firewall issue as OMV was using a different port than the Ubuntu server (my cameras are on a vlan without access to anything else other than the ports I specifically allow but everything else was pretty painless.
Overall, I feel like NFS took more work but I'm happier with the final result because the ownership/permissions are consistent across client/server. It also FEELS like it's slightly faster but I didn't benchmark it.
EDIT
I've found an even better way to mount the share - autofs
This runs as a service and creates a "ghost" directory on the main file system.
As soon as anything tries to access the directory, it (impressively quickly) mounts the share. This also means that if the share managed to unmount for any reason, it should come back up again since Nextcloud and Deluge are always reading the contents of the directory
